# DownloadStringAsync. List<T> ничего не возвращает

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public static List<string> GetFileNameModePack(string url)
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    var client = new WebClient();

    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        MatchCollection files = Regex.Matches(e.Result, @"(?<=<a href="")[^""]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            list.Add(files[i].Value);
        }
    };
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));

    return list;
}
```

Почему `list` всегда возвращает 0?

`files` не пуст и если в `DownloadStringCompleted` обращаться к конкретному индексу (пример: files[5].Value), то результат возвращает.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

```
public static async Task<List<string>> GetFileNameModePack(string url)
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    var client = new WebClient();

    Task<string> readFile = client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(url));
    string result = await readFile;

    MatchCollection files = Regex.Matches(result, @"(?<=<a href="")[^""]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    for (int i = 5; i < files.Count; i++)
    {
        list.Add(files[i].Value);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Единственное непонятно — почему если в папке по указанной ссылке большое количество файлов (> 500), то выбрасывает исключение `System.Net.WebException`: `Запрос был прерван: Соединение было неожиданно закрыто.`

Может кто-то знает? :)

Comment: Возможно, сборщик мусора уничтожает объект `WebClient`. Оберните его использование в `using` или сделайте полем класса.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, неа, пробовал.

Comment: Может timeout маленький?

Comment: @Anxis, нет, пробовал увеличивать. Походу гиблое дело(( придумал немного другой вариант, буду пробовать реализовать.